# DGS Framework: how to provide additional data to the data fetcher?

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, netflix-dgs

I have a example DgsQuery:

```
@DgsQuery
public List<Sensor> sensors(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {
     
    SensorType sensorType = SensorType.newBuilder()
            .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build();
    

    Sensor sensor = new Sensor();
    sensor.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    sensor.setName("foo");
    sensor.setSensorType(sensorType);

    return Arrays.asList(sensor);
}
```

And a data fetcher:

```
@DgsData(parentType = DgsConstants.SENSOR.TYPE_NAME, field = DgsConstants.SENSOR.SensorType)
public CompletableFuture<SensorType> sensorType(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {
    Sensor sensor = dfe.getSource();
    UUID sensorTypeId = UUID.fromString(sensor.getSensorType().getId());

    // fetch sensorType by ID from DB, map to generated class and return
    LOGGER.info("Would now fetch sensorType with ID {} via RPC or whatever you want ;)", sensorTypeId);

    return null;
}
```

In the dataFetcher I need to be able to access some additional data / objects that are initialized in the @DgsQuery method. How can I do this?

**Example usecase:**
In the @DgsQuery there is a Entity that has been loaded from the database, I need to pass this entity to the data fetcher. 
Currently I have only access to the Sensor object via

```
    Sensor sensor = dfe.getSource();
```

but none of some further data that might be already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Found it out:

```
@DgsQuery
public DataFetcherResult<List<Sensor>> sensors(DgsDataFetchingEnvironment dfe) {

    SensorType sensorType = SensorType.newBuilder()
            .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
            .build();

    Sensor sensor = new Sensor();
    sensor.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    sensor.setName("foo");
    sensor.setSensorType(sensorType);

    return DataFetcherResult.<List<Sensor>>newResult()
            .data(Arrays.asList(sensor))
            .localContext("foo")
            .build();
}
```

and in the data fetcher:

```
Object localContext = dfe.getLocalContext(); ( --> "foo")
```